# multiple job submission issue on HPC which uses temporary folder before writing results

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run multiple commands through one job script, and it just so happens that the command to execute requires tmp memory to write result before actually saving the *.hrr result.
Here is my script

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12
#PBS -l walltime=2:00:00
#PBS -m mem=25G
#PBS -V
#PBS -M kalyani.dhusia@einsteinmed.org
#PBS -N spring_kaly


cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR


module load python/2.7.8/gcc.4.4.7
module load perl/5.28.0/gcc.4.9.2
module load numpy/1.9.0/python.2.7.8
module load cython/0.22/python.2.7.8

./springdb/source/runSPRING.pl -seqname Q96F46_Q8NFR9 -datadir ./KALYANI/Q96F46_Q8NFR9
./springdb/source/runSPRING.pl -seqname Q29983_Q68D85 -datadir ./KALYANI/Q29983_Q68D85
./springdb/source/runSPRING.pl -seqname Q9Y5H8_Q9Y5E6 -datadir ./KALYANI/Q9Y5H8_Q9Y5E6
./springdb/source/runSPRING.pl -seqname P13688_P08514 -datadir ./KALYANI/P13688_P08514
./springdb/source/runSPRING.pl -seqname P07333_P29322 -datadir ./KALYANI/P07333_P29322
./springdb/source/runSPRING.pl -seqname Q13349_P05556 -datadir ./KALYANI/Q13349_P05556


wait
```

Error that I get is the following

```
Read Fasta
Search results will be written to /tmp//kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt//hhm//P06340_P43629A.hhr
Reading in 8290068 column state sequences with a total of 1874100330 residues
Error in /gs/gsfs0/users/kdhusia/springdb/source/HHsearch//hhsuite/bin/hhblits: memalign could not allocate memory of 1874100330 bytes, Cannot allocate memory.
Is your max memory size sufficient? (Check using '$ ulimit -a' under Linux)

$ cp /tmp//kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt//hhm//P06340_P43629A.a3m /tmp/kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt/hhm/BeJe1XUSEP.in.a3m

Error: command 'cp /tmp//kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt//hhm//P06340_P43629A.a3m /tmp/kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt/hhm/BeJe1XUSEP.in.a3m' returned error code 1

cp: cannot stat `/tmp//kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt//hhm//P06340_P43629A.a3m': No such file or directory
ERROR: cannot open /tmp/kdhusia/SPRING_P06340_P43629A-P06340_P43629B.txt/hhm/BeJe1XUSEP.in.a3m!
```

Any suggestions on how could I fix this?

Comment: the first error message suggests you do not have enough memory. Also, there is no `cp` in your script, and though you use (a single) `wait`, there is no job launched in the background (e.g. no `&`), so you might want to double check the script you posted match what you are really doing.